# Why does using res.writeHead in NextJS cause a permanent redirect?

Tags: node.js, electron, next.js

There's a part in my code, to check if something is true, then redirect.

This is done here:

```
static async getInitialProps({ res }) {
        let accessToken = settings.get('access_token');
        if (accessToken) {
            if (res) {
                res.writeHead(301, {
                    Location: '/dashboard'
                });
                res.end();
                return {};
            }
        }
    }
```

And it redirects the first time, but always makes a call to this page with the code above.

If I restart my app, it takes me immediately to `/dashboard` **without** making a call to this first page. It skips it entirely. What could be causing this behaviour?

I've noticed that I can fix it by deleting the app's AppData in `%appdata%/my-app`.

I'm also using:

```
const Store = require('electron-store');
const settings = new Store();
```

Here is a log of my terminal showing this:

```
> electron-twitch-app@1.0.0 start C:\NodeApps\electron-twitch-app
> electron .

Defining routes from exportPathMap
(node:12868) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
event - compiled successfully
event - build page: /
wait  - compiling...
event - compiled successfully
event - build page: /dashboard
wait  - compiling...
event - compiled successfully
PS C:\NodeApps\electron-twitch-app> npm start

> electron-twitch-app@1.0.0 start C:\NodeApps\electron-twitch-app
> electron .


Defining routes from exportPathMap
(node:7500) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
event - compiled successfully
event - build page: /dashboard
wait  - compiling...
event - compiled successfully
```

Notice it's as I said - the first time, it calls `/`, and then redirects to `/dashboard`. The second time, it just goes straight to `/dashboard`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, using:

```
app.commandLine.appendSwitch("disable-http-cache");
```

Fixes my issue.

Is there any other solution other than this?